# How to create a os.walk() function which compares the folders and subfolders of two directories?

Tags: python, for-loop, os.walk, file-comparison

here‘s my problem: Let‘s say I want to create a file syncing function that goes through all the  folders and subfolders of two similar directories and detects all the common folders/subfolders of those two directories. I gave it a try by combining the os.walk module with the filecmp module. Here´s what my code looks like so far:

```
import filecmp
import os

src=r"C:\Users\j2the\Documents\Test3"
dst=r"C:\Users\j2the\Documents\Test4"


comparison = filecmp.dircmp(dst, src)

for dirpath,dirnames,filenames in os.walk(src):
    for folders in dirnames:
        if folders in comparison.common_dirs:
            print(folders)
            src_folder=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath,folders))
            dst_folder=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dst,folders))
            folder_comparison = filecmp.dircmp(dst_folder, src_folder)

            for dirpath1,dirnames1,filenames1 in os.walk(src_folder):

                for subfolders in dirnames1:
                    if subfolders in folder_comparison.common_dirs:
                        print(subfolders)
                        src_subfolder=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath1,subfolders))
                        dst_subfodler=os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dst_folder,subfolders))
                        subfolder_comparison=filecmp.dircmp(dst_subfodler,src_subfolder)
```

It‘s a very simple code. However, this code is only working with directories which have max. 2 subfolders.  If I wanted to analyze directories with more subfolders, I would have to add tons of nested loops to my code. Surely there is another way to do that, right? I was thinking about creating a while loop that keeps going through every subfolder and compare them until there‘s no subfolder left, but I simply couldn‘t figure out how to do it. Any help/input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Doesn’t `os.walk` generate a tuple for each subfolder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `filecmp.dircmp`. Instead, make two calls to `os.walk` with the two directories you want to compare, `zip` the output of the two generators and use set intersection on the two sub-directories from the output to find the common sub-directories.

Note that the key to making the recursive traversal work is to perform in-place replacement to the sub-directories returned by both generators so that only sub-directories that are common to both of the current directories are retained for deeper traversal and further comparisons:

```
import os
for (root1, dirs1, _), (root2, dirs2, _) in zip(os.walk('dir1'), os.walk('dir2')):
    dirs1[:] = dirs2[:] = set(dirs1).intersection(dirs2)
    for common_dir in dirs1:
      print('Common sub-directory of {} and {}: {}'.format(root1, root2, common_dir))
```

From the documentation of [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk):

> When `topdown` is `True`, the caller can modify the `dirnames` list in-place
>   (perhaps using `del` or slice assignment), and `walk()` will only recurse
>   into the subdirectories whose names remain in `dirnames`; this can be
>   used to prune the search...

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple trick that works (testing on a mac). The os.walk function returns a generator of the directory tree, which can be yielded into a list. However, due to potentially different root directory names, I removed the first element in each list item.

Edit: This only compares the directory structure and not content.

```
res1 = [r[1:] for r in os.walk(src)]
res2 = [r[1:] for r in os.walk(dst)]

comparison = res1 == res2
```